# How to fire button onclientclick from another button click event both in updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have code like this:

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveBooks" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="col-md-4 form-control" Width="8%" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#333333" OnClick="btnSaveBooks_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnActive" runat="server" Text="" OnClientClick="ohSnap('Task finished.', 'green');"/>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="ohsnap"></div>
```

But how to active btnActive's OnClientClick in btnSaveBooks's OnClick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to call JS function

in code behind

```
protected void btnSaveBooks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel2, UpdatePanel2.GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('FiveDot File uploaded successfully');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make client Id mode of button 'btnActive" static

```
  ClientIDMode="Static"
```

2)Then in your 'btnSaveBooks_Click' Method use below Line

```
  document.getElementById('btnActive').click(); return false;
```

Comment: Hi, are you means put this line?
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>document.getElementById('btnActive').click(); return false;</script>", true);